# Selecting parent records of children that meet multiple conditions (but not together) with SQLite

Tags: java, c#, sql, database, sqlite

I don't know why I can wrap my head around this query. I think I am not asking the correct question which is why I am struggling to find an answer.

I have two tables. `items` and `skus`. I am trying to identify `items` that have skus that meet both the following conditions:

1. Has a SKU with a `price_date` > *specified date*
2. Has a SKU with a `custom` = 1.

Using the below example:

**items**

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My Item 1 |
| 2 | My Item 2 |

**skus**

| ID | ItemID | SKU | price_date | custom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1234 | **2020-12-11*** | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 5678 | 2020-05-01 | **1*** |
| 2 | 2 | ABDC | 1900-01-01 | 0 |

I am trying to get my query to return "My Item 1" from the `items` table as it has one sku that is greater than my specified date and another that has a custom value equaling 1. The problem is that my query only "hits" if a SKU meets both conditions together (meaning 1 sku must met all conditions). In the table you can see that SKU ID 1 meets my first condition and SKU ID 2 meets my seconds condition for parent item "My Item 1"

The below query return nothing even though the skus for My Item 1 meet the conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM items
LEFT JOIN skus ON items.ID=skus.ItemID
GROUP BY items.ID
HAVING sku.price_date>date('2020-12-01') AND sku.custom=1
```

How can I make the query look at all child items together, and then return the item if all conditions are met, regardless of if the conditions hit in a single sku together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of JOIN skus, we need to first figure out which ItemID-s qualify..  I am using MCNT as table prefix Multiple Conditions Not Together...

```
SELECT [ItemID]
  FROM [StackOver].[dbo].[MCNTskus]
  Group By [ItemID]
  Having 
       max([price_date]) > ('2020-12-01')
     and 
       max([custom])  = 1
```

Then use that as FROM and do LeftJoin of items

```
With qualSKUs as
(SELECT [ItemID]
  FROM [StackOver].[dbo].[MCNTskus]
  Group By [ItemID]
  Having 
       max([price_date]) > ('2020-12-01')
     and 
       max([custom])  = 1
)
SELECT MCNTitems.ID, MCNTitems.Name
    FROM qualSKUs
LEFT JOIN MCNTitems ON MCNTitems.ID=qualSKUs.ItemID
GROUP BY qualSKUs.ItemID,MCNTitems.ID, MCNTitems.Name
```

Resulting in

```
ID  Name
1   My Item 1
```

Comment: `max` was the answer thanks. Simply adding it to the `HAVING` comparisons did the trick as I was simply looking for the items that qualified. Thank you.